# Why is my Kafka Transformer's StateStore not accessible?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to implement a Transformer class

```
public class StreamSorterByTimeStampWithDelayTransformer < V > 
    implements Transformer< Long, V, KeyValue< Long, V > >
```

The constructor for the class creates a StateStore for each instance, thus:

```
this.state_store_name = "state_store_" + this.hashCode();

KeyValueBytesStoreSupplier key_value_store_supplier = Stores.persistentKeyValueStore( state_store_name );
StoreBuilder< KeyValueStore< String, V > > key_value_store_builder = 
    Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder( key_value_store_supplier, Serdes.String(), v_instance.getSerde() );
stream_builder.addStateStore( key_value_store_builder );
```

The Transformer `init` method references the StateStore thus:

```
public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.key_value_store = (KeyValueStore< String, V >) context.getStateStore( state_store_name );
    // schedule a punctuate() method every "poll_ms" (wall clock time)
    this.context.schedule( this.poll_ms, PunctuationType.WALL_CLOCK_TIME, 
            (timestamp) -> pushOutOldEnoughEntries() );
}
```

I think I must be leaving out a step because when the getStateStore call is made, it
results in an exception saying:

```
Processor KSTREAM-TRANSFORM-0000000003 has no access to StateStore
```

What am I omitting or doing wrong?

Answer (score 13):

You need to attach the store to the transformer:

```java
stream.transform(..., this.state_store_name);
```